# How to add a dynamic row on click of button in a table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I am new to the react Js as well front end. Here, I have a table which is like

```
<div className="col-xs-12 " id="scrollableTable">
                        <Table striped condensed hover id="jobData">
                            <thead style={backgrounColour}>
                            <tr>
                                <th className='serial-column'>Sr.No.</th>
                                <th className='company-column'>Company Name</th>
                                <th className='technology-column'>Technology</th>
                                <th className='job-column'>Job Title</th>
                                <th className='total-score-column'>Total Score</th>
                                <th className='average-score-column'>Average Score</th>
                            </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody>{this.props.jobData.map(function (item, key) {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={key}>
                                        <td><b style={compName}>{item.id}</b></td>
                                        <td><b style={compName}>{item.attributes.companyName}</b></td>
                                        <td>Xamarian Developer</td>
                                        <td>{item.attributes.name}</td>
                                        <td><b style={compName}>30</b></td>
                                        <td><b style={compName}>30</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                            })}</tbody>
                        </Table>
                    </div>
```

I do have one button which is like

```
<button className = "btn btn-default">Add Row </button>
```

It looks like

[image]

Now, What I want to have is that on click of this button,

[image]

This should get added as a first row in this table.

Actually, I want to have an idea how can I do this? I tried by adding a static row in this but It did not work. So, I am asking this question.

Any help will be great for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### FOR SINGLE EDITABLE ROW

1. Create separate component holding the row you would like to add, after clicking the button.
2. Add state property that will be used to define if your 'edition row' is visible.
3. It should have default state `false` (as it should not be visible at initial render)

   `this.state = {
      isRowAddingEditorVisible: false
   }`

When "Add row" button is clicked, set state of that above property, to `true`

`this.setState({ isRowAddingEditorVisible: true });`

And in your component that holds whole table implement it like this:

```
<tbody>
{this.state.isRowAddingEditorVisible && <RowAddingEditor />}     // <--- HERE
{this.props.jobData.map(function (item, key) {
     return (
       <JobTableRow key={key} data={item}>
     )
 })}
</tbody>
```

This way you dont need to modify original data that forms the table.

And JobTableRow would hold everything you have as row currently. 
It provides better separation, readability and your closer to SRP (Single Responsibility Princple - code/method/component doing one thing only)

Check this fiddle to get the idea:
https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/167786/

Also `{this.state.isRowAddingEditorVisible && <RowAddingEditor />}` - this is called short circuting. 
Am using the fact that `$booleanValue && <ReactComponent/>` will evaluate to `<ReactComponent>` when `$booleanValue` is `true` and will evaluate to `nothing` (visually speaking) when `$booleanValue` is `false`

#### FOR MULTIPLE EDITABLE ROWS

https://jsfiddle.net/n5u2wwjg/173218/

**Hint 1:**
I used Math.random() to get unique IDs for rows. It is just simple, fast, example solution and in that form should not be used in production code.
Usually unique IDs generators are based on Math.random(), but randomized bit more with some additional code.

**Hint 2:**
Remember that when POSTing row to server, you also need to remove its ID from state.

**Hint 3:**
Usually when you have method starting with `get` and returning some DOM elements you use in `render` method, it is signal that contents of this method should be moved to separate React component.

**Hint 4:**
In above example I use ES6 syntax. Learn it if you don't know it yet, it's your friend :). Search "ES6 features tutorial".

1. spread operator - ...
2. arrow function - => (anonymous also - not stored anywhere or named)

Comment: If he needs to add only one row, it's fine. But your code will not fulfill adding multiple editable rows.

Comment: I want to add only one row.

Comment: sure thing:)) glad I could help. @MithunGS yes, but I assumed that UX wise it should work like that - it s visible and you can add a row using it, or it s not. You cant let your UI present multiple controls for same thing, that just doesnt make sense I guess :D?

Comment: @GaneshKaspate could you please mark this as an answer if you believe it is an answer in the end? Thanks :)

Comment: Yes sure Perfect answer : -)  It will be really helpful for me If you tell me How we can add multiple rows ?

Comment: @GaneshKaspate I ve edited my answer, providing solutions for both one and many rows. Have fun :) Thanks for marking it an answer!

Comment: Thanks a lot great answer :-)

Comment: thumbs up! have fun coding

Answer (score 1):

First you have to keep the `this.props.jobData` in `state`, Then `OnClick` of the button you have to update `this.state.jobData`

add a field in `item` to identify if it's an editable row or non editable. Let's say `isEditable`

The code will be:

```
<tbody>{this.state.jobData.map(function (item, key) {
                           if (!item.isEditable) {
                                return (
                                    <tr key={key}>
                                        <td><b style={compName}>{item.id}</b></td>
                                        <td><b style={compName}>{item.attributes.companyName}</b></td>
                                        <td>Xamarian Developer</td>
                                        <td>{item.attributes.name}</td>
                                        <td><b style={compName}>30</b></td>
                                        <td><b style={compName}>30</b></td>
                                    </tr>
                                )
                           } else {
                                return (
                                   //Add your editable row here
                                )
                           }

                            })}</tbody>
```

Comment: Sorry but he does not need to hold that data in state. It s not necessary. Modifying whole data set by extending it with this one `isEditable` field for sake of one row actually (EditionRow) is also huge overkill.

Comment: also data may come from server and may not be hold anywhere in the app directly, so extending it for sake of visualization of non-data row is not only overkill, but also may not be possible without holding that data just for that sake OR modifying data structure in DB - both being bad ideas.

Comment: I'm not sure about his requirements, as per my answer he can add multiple editable rows and edit existing rows. Anyway let him decide

Comment: Yes , I don't need to hold that data in state

Comment: Actually, table which has the data that is coming from a server, But A new row  or you can say a div which will appear before the first row of that table .

Comment: That row or div can appear only if user has clicked on a button.

Comment: If it's one row at a time @azrahel s answer is perfect

Comment: Thanks a lot @MithunGS For yout time and answer. It will help me.

Answer (score 1):

@azrahel gave right answer about first problem (modify table view), **below I'm writing about how it should work later** - action triggered from that 'mini form'.

In short - it's data driven. Update data, view will be updated.

`this.props.jobData.map` shows that rows are from `this.props.jobData` array. Add row means then add to array. There is one problem - you can't mutate props. Props are passed from parent component then you have to update data in parent. To handle this you should have `addJob` method in parent and pass this handler as prop (like jobData, read docs).

But ... **probably this array is not a local data, was fetched from server**. If you want to update this on server (push to DB, to be available to others) then yon need to post data to server (it will store it in DB). In simplest scenario post request will return new, updated array. Updated data, passed to component should render component with new array (with new row). It's up to you if 'editing row' should be still visible or not.

Comment: Technically speaking you **can** mutate values that are state of parent component (it s not a good idea design-wise, but that is different story) and are passed as props. Alongside data that forms table you can pass callback method that will modify that data - no problems here. You even wrote it yourself. Still, that is not a good design .
Sending data you suggest to server, just to render this one row is very bad idea performance-wise. Also it s not standard practice (which is better) so really no need for that.

Comment: Question is about "adding dynamic row", not about "how it should work after you use that dynamic row and should it be posted to server or not" so sorry but I will still downvote it :(
Your answer mixes it all up and may create further confusion instead of clarifying things and helping PO.

Comment: I wrote about mutating own props. For you it can be obvious but for newcommers it can be a problem. I wrote about updating remote source not only for updating/reloading updated array. It was simple example to show 'the flow', we aren't discussing here about optimizations, pagination, fetching more, optimistic update, sticking row etc. `I don't care if you still downvoting` - I'm just giving IMHO helpful hints for anyone needing help. I often found helpful things in comments, not in accepted, specific answer (sometimes misleading or outdated).

Comment: Thanks for the reply.. Actually, what is going to happen is that, on click of that Add/Paste job  it is going to send an API request to server with this data and then It ultimately going to uodate the data of that table, So, its going to modify that jobData .

Comment: Ask a new question (and link here) when problems arise